# I'm looking for parking lot

Tags: word-usage

We were looking for parking lot.

My son asked me, "Why are you keep going."

"**I'm looking for parking lot.**" I told him.

How to say a space that has no car parking?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about a place that lacks car parking facilities or do you want just to say that there is no spot in the parking lot where you could park your car?

Comment: Yes. @CookieMonster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space in a parking lot where you leave your car after parking it is "officially" called a parking spot or [**a parking space**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parking_space). You can also refer to it simply as a spot. Parking lots in big cities can consist of hundreds, if not thousands, of such spots. So, your conversation with your son could be rephrased as follows:

> — Why do you keep driving, Dad?
>   — **I'm trying to find a free (or open) parking spot to park the car.**

Comment: I've often heard "empty parking spot" along with "free parking spot" in everyday conversation

Comment: Informally, if the person I'm talking to knows we're in a parking lot, I might also just say "I'm trying to find a space" or "...find a spot".

Comment: I would say *I'm looking for an **open** parking spot* or simply, *I'm looking for a place to park (but the lot is completely full)*.  Which doesn't often happen since my wife has magic powers when it comes to **finding an open space** -- a parking space always seems to **open up** just when we arrive.